# Filtering List/ICollection by Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

I have a List/ICollection from a database query and I want to filter it by date - something like

```
// razor syntax
var results = db.Query(fooBars).ToList();
var overdue = results.Where( x => x.Date < DateTime.Now );
```

This is throwing an error

```
 CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
```

Any ideas how I might implement this?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I don't mean to confuse the issue but I am under the impression that saving the results in an object and working on that to populate the HTML page is a better approach than querying the database multiple times. Is that correct? e.g.

```
// #1.
db.Query("SELECT this FROM that WHERE Date < CAST(GetDate() as Date)");
// versus
results.Where( x => x.Date < DateTime.Now ) // doesn't work but you get the idea :-)

// #2
db.Quer("SELECT count(this) FROM that WHERE status = 'COMPLETE'")
// versus
results.Select( x => x.status = "COMPLETE" ).Count
```

Cheers.

Comment: I think it's actually better to perform the query with one single statement, rather than bringing down the entire table and filtering locally.
Also, I think your error isn't coming from the db query, but from somewhere else, but I'm not familiar with ASP.NET WebMatrix or WebPages. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The page is a dashboard so there are couple of elements on it including overdue items, category counts etc. So some better examples might be 1. SELECT this FROM that WHERE Date < CAST(GetDate() as Date) vs results.Where( x => x.Date < DateTime.Now ) 2. SELECT count(this) FROM that WHERE status = "COMPLETE" vs. results.Select( x => x.status = "COMPLETE" ).Count

Comment: Are you sure that the linq lines are causing the error?

Comment: I don't think the error cause is on LINQ. There must be some other cause of issue..

Comment: Urgh! I later did results.Where( x => x.Date < DateTime.Now ).Count on the page instead of results.Where( x => x.Date < DateTime.Now ).Count() [round brackets missing] and that broke it. (sad face)